# Utility for managing window locations

Tags: windows-7, windows

Any suggestions for a free or cheap app for managing window locations/placement in Windows 7?

I'm constantly remoting in and out of my workstation with a varying number of monitors and would like to setup profiles of windows placement that can be run to readjust my window locations depending on the number of screens I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a huge fan of [WinSplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/), which I learned about from [Jeff's blog on large monitor issues](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/08/the-large-display-paradox.html). To be honest I haven't tried it over Remote Desktop, but it works great locally.

Answer (score 1):

Have not tried it but looks promising.

http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2339650,00.asp